# issue on calling Weather rest api in Bluemix environment

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm getting error while calling Weather Company Rest API services within Bluemix. Using the same code in local environment, i can get the response from this call. Please share your advise.

Code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    ResponseEntity<WeatherStatusWrapper> jsonString = restTemplate.exchange(srcURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, WeatherStatusWrapper.class);
```

Error:

> 12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM ERR App [ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest:982'
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at [internal classes]
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:289)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at com.techm.bluemix.smarterairport.ServiceImpl.WeatherServiceImpl.trackWeatherForecast(WeatherServiceImpl.java:94)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at com.techm.bluemix.smarterairport.Controller.WeatherController.trackWeatherForecast(WeatherController.java:47)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   12/27/2016 10:06:43 AM  ERR App at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing a 401 Unauthorized Error. The request requires authentication. Username & Password can be obtained from the CONNECTIONS TAB-> VIEW CREDENTIALS in Bluemix Application Dashboard

Comment: https://e694bbXXXXXa42-485a-8659-46a574267f78:DnRXXXXXF8@twcservice.mybluemix.net. Passed credential with host

Comment: Can you set authorization manually?                                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider(); credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password)); httpClient.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);